# How to add inputed numbers in string.(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i add all imputed numbers in a string?

Ex:

> input:
>   5 5 3 5
>   output
>   18

and it must supports ('-')
Ex.

> input
>   -5 5 3 5
>   output
>   8

I write something like this:

```
x = raw_input()
print sum(map(int,str(x)))
```

and it adds normally if x>0
But what to do with ('-') ?
I understand that i need to use split() but my knowledge is not enough (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, you just need to `split` the string on spaces. Splitting will produce the list of strings `['-5', '5', '3', '5']`. Then you can do the rest of the `map` and `sum` as you intended.

```
>>> s = '-5 5 3 5'
>>> sum(map(int, s.split()))
8
```

Answer (score 0):

its simple

```
>>> input = raw_input('Enter your input: ')
    Enter your input: 5 5 10 -10
>>> list_numbers = [int(item) for item in input.split(' ')]
>>> print list_numbers
    [5, 5, 10, -10]
```

And after what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line:
sum(map(int, raw_input().split()))